# Enable posting by email

Tags: google-groups

I am participating in a Google Group, and it is not possible to post by email:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     foo@googlegroups.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
The group foo@googlegroups.com does not allow posting through email.
```

Is there some documentation online that explains how to enable posting by email, and that I can send to the Group's owner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Post by Email or by Web**

- `Information > General information > Posting options > Allow posting by email`
- `Information > General information > Posting options > Allow users to post to the group on the web`

**Should Message be Available on The Web?**

- `Information > Content control > Archive options > Archive messages to the group`

**Contact Owners by Email**

1. `Permissions > Access Permissions > Contact the owners of this Group > Public`
2. See *"Post by Email"* point above (required too).

**Change Group Type / Reset All Options**

`Information > Advanced > Reset group > Select a group type`

P.S. [The official documentation](https://support.google.com/groups) seems to lack this topic.

Comment: Why is "Contact the owners of this Group" necessary?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal, thought the author wants it too. Changed my answer, thank you

Comment: The format of your answer is very clear and helpful.

Comment: That first one, `Information > General Information > Posting Options > Allow posting by email`, is 1 of 4 or 5 similar checkboxes. It's the only one that wasn't checked, took a while to find that.

Answer (score 6):

That's a setting that the group owner has set. You can't override that. You'll need to go to the [Google Groups web interface](http://groups.google.com) to post. (The address for the group is probably in the footer of the email you've been receiving, with other useful information.)

The allowed post mechanisms are defined on the General Information page for the group.

- [General Information help page](http://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464972?hl=en&ref_topic=2459487)

From the help page:

[image: screen shot]

On the General Information page

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Thanks, but in my question I am asking for documentation that I can send to the owner on how to precisely change *that setting*.

Comment: Yes, and the documentation is there on the help page to which I have linked.

Comment: I have added a couple of screen shots for your convenience.

Comment: So there is no official documentation detailing how to *change* permissions to allow users post by email? (which is what I had asked for)

Comment: How much more official than a Google Support page do you want? Granted, it's fairly shy on details, but that's what they provide.

Comment: Well, if that's the best there is, then that's what I'll use. As for the screenshot, I already have created that myself. You may remove the first part of your answer starting with: *"That's a setting that the group owner has set. You can't override that."*. That's confusing because not being able to post by email is exactly the *reason* why I want to send information to the owner.

Comment: No, I think I'll leave it in. Stack Exchange is all about being a repository of knowledge, and that information is likely to be helpful to future readers. I also think it's likely that the group owner is well aware of that setting, since they've changed it from the default.

Comment: Then please mark it up as additional information, because to me it is confusing that the rationale for my question is part of the answer. The group owner, by the way, is totally new to Google Groups.